# Converting an equirectangular RGB image and a corresponding depth map into point clouds withoud knowing the camera pose

Tags: 3d, point-clouds

I am trying to convert an equirectangular RGB image and a matching equirectangular depth map to point clouds.
But the thing is we do not know the camera pose.

Is it possible to convert them to point cloud file?

Thank you for your help in advance.